# my vb.net encryption result does not match the xcode encryption result given the same input parameters

Tags: vb.net, xcode, encryption, aes

I have set up a method in vb.net and in xcode for encrypting a string using as far as i can tell the same parameters for an AES encryption.

I've looked all over the place but cannot find information on whether they use the same encryption algorithm and settings.

this is the vb.net code:

```
Dim encryptAES As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding()
Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform

encryptAES.Key = encoding.GetBytes("12345678901234567890123456789032")
encryptAES.IV = encoding.GetBytes("1234567890123416")
encryptAES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
encryptAES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
encryptor = encryptAES.CreateEncryptor

Dim input As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes("hello")

Dim result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length)

Dim hex As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - 1
    hex = hex & result(i).ToString("X2")
Next
ConsoleWrite(hex)
```

which matches the output of this php encryption:

```
<?php
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    $key256 = '12345678901234567890123456789032';
    $iv =  '1234567890123416';
    $cleartext = 'hello';
    printf("plainText: %s\n\n",$cleartext);
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key256, $iv) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$cleartext );
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
        printf("256-bit encrypted result:\n%s\n\n",bin2hex($cipherText));
    }
?>
```

And here's the mac code:

```
IV = [@"1234567890123416" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog([IV base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]);

NSData * localKey = [@"12345678901234567890123456789032" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog([localKey base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]);

NSLog(@"encode plaintext:");
NSLog([self.data base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]);

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, 
                                     localKey, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     IV, //initialization vector 
                                     [self.data mutableBytes], [self.data length], //input
                                     buffer, bufferSize, //output
                                     &numBytesEncrypted );

self.data = [self.data initWithBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
NSLog(@"encode end result:");
NSLog([self.data base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]);
```

So as far as I can tell the mac code must be incorrect as it returns a different value (the same length).

Here are the debug dumps from both the pac and mac versions.

pc (values in base64):

```
key: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMzI=
iv: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQxNg==
plaintext: aGVsbG8=
encrypted: oiUIdi9StezV93+nXctCKw==
```

mac (values in base 64):

```
key: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMzI=
iv: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQxNg==
plaintext: aGVsbG8=
encrypted: rU5MgfNIjx7zqD5Cdh2mlA==
```

I also had a look at endianness here is the pc encryped base64 with both endianness and neither match the mac version:

```
oiUIdi9StezV93+nXctCKw==
K0LLXad/99XstVIvdgglog==
```

I've now run a test where I've set the key to be 32 0's and the IV to be 16 0's (so endianness should hopefully not matter) and with two more tests heres the results from mac:

```
BfG2gjzkooiJCXgIQJKyZg== (iOS 5 on device)
n9KJXqThiuKyrNPjo7V7PA== (iOS 5 in simulator)
cCH116bIlLeUOxNDwFt2rg== (iOS 4.3 in simulator)
```

WTH? all parameters are identical, only change is which version to compile for and each encryption is different...

and the pc result:

```
wjXeJNI54DzI43fGBPymew==
```

When inputting the mac encrypted text into the pc to decrypt, I get a 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.' error.

Any information anyone could provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Both the mac and pc versions involve first creating a byte array from the sample text, and it is this byte array that is then passed to the encryption algorithm.  I would start by comparing those byte arrays to make sure you are encrypting the same data. It looks like in both cases you have utf8 and AES128, but it never hurts to be sure.

Next, the result of the encryption algorithm is also a byte array, which must then be re-encoded as a string.  Looking at your results, I see not just two different values, but two completely different *kinds* of characters.  That tells me that the re-encoding may be off. Again, you want to compare the byte arrays.

In both cases, to ensure an accurate compare, I would base64 encode the arrays.

Comment: Definitely agree with @Joel Coehoorn, start with the byte arrays that are produced from the strings. Look into endianness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Thanks. Checked the inputs, and both match using base64string. the outputs are still different event using base64strings:
pc : oiUIdi9StezV93+nXctCKw==
mac: rU5MgfNIjx7zqD5Cdh2mlA== @Chris Haas thanks, will look at endianness next

Comment: Check out the helpful answer here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/what-is-the-difference-between-these-aes-encryption-methods